# Comparing current date to a repeating day of the month

Tags: php

How would I compare the current day, in any format to a static repeating day of the month.

For example I have `due date` of `5` which is when my rent is due and I want compare the current date every day so that on the `5th` of each month I can then know how many days till the `5th` or since the `5th`

Is there a way to do this without setting my `due date` to a `timestamp` or similar that I then update as it is reached?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
function date_diff_in_days($date1, $date2) {
  $date1 = strtotime($date1);
  $date2 = strtotime($date2);
  $diff = $date2 - $date1;
  return floor($diff/86400); // 86400 is one day in seconds
}

// compare the due date to the current date
$days = date_diff_in_days($due_date, time());
$past_due = $days < 0;
$days = abs($days);

// show your result
echo 'Your bill is '.($past_due 
  ? 'past due by '.$days.' days.' 
  : 'due in '.$days.' days.');
```

Comment: I don't think I can `strtotime` something like `5`

Comment: well you would not `strtotime(5)`, you would `strtotime('2013-12-05')`, the 5th of December. If you need to figure out what december is, you could `date('Y-m-', strtotime('-1 month')).$day_of_month`, where $day_of_month = 5, and `strtotime('-1 month')` finds today minus 1 month.